# how to swift async block passed

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

```
func datakontrol(){

let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost.192.168.1.40.xip.io:8888/store1.php")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

    if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

        guard let telefon = jsonObj!["telefon"] as? String else { return }
        GlobalVariables.telefonum = telefon
    }
}).resume()
```

When I try trace this code jump from dataTask to end of code.I think ask a wrong question. I want this code is completed. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try trace this code jump from dataTask to end of code

Because `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` is an `asynchronous` or simply an `async` method.
According to official document for this method:

> Creates a task that retrieves the contents of the specified URL, then
>   calls a handler upon completion.

**Async** is (as the name suggests) is an **asynchronous** call meaning we are saying that please do this work , I will come back to you, then when it completes its work, it calls the **completion handler** (in other words it is saying I have completed my work) , so if you put the `print` statement before `if let jsonObj = try?...` like `print("I have completed my work")` , you will see it will be printed after sometime. or you can put a break/debug point before `if let jsonObj = try?...` to see if control of your program reaches there or not.

Note : Another way to understand this is that an `async` function doesnt block the current function from executing, it does its work in background and when it completes its work, which in your specific case "**Getting the data from server**" , it calls its completion handler, and control of the program goes back to the completion handler of this `async` function

Comment: Thank you for your help. I add print and sleep now its working. Again thank you.

Comment: @ÜmitGündüz Good, I dont know what is the usecase here, so I am unable to recognize where you need `sleep` but small advice is that you should try to avoid using `sleep` as much as possible in your code

Comment: I use views between data transfer maybe sleep terrible solve but working.

Answer (score 0):

```
func datakontrol() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost.192.168.1.40.xip.io:8888/store1.php")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

            guard let telefon = jsonObj!["telefon"] as? String else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  GlobalVariables.telefonum = telefon
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: firstly sorry for my English, I think ask a wrong question. I want this code is completed. now your code is jump from let url = NSURL to resume()

Comment: by "jump" you mean debugging not entering to completionHandler block ?, if yes did you try put break point inside that block ?

Comment: @mihatel thank you the problem is solved.